# How do I process application/x-www-form-urlencoded via a custom endpoint

Tags: apex, apexrest

I want to process a POST to a custom APEX REST endpoint that is being posted from SLACK with a Content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded

When I inspect the body of the post in Hookbin it contains one parameter called "payload" and in it is a URL Encoded string.

I have created the following class and I have made it public and shared the class so that unauthenticated posts can be received without a challenge for credentials or requiring a token.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/slack/*')
global class REST_Slack  {

    @HttpPost global static void doPost() {
        System.debug('Response:');
        System.debug(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString());
        RestContext.response.headers.put('Content-Type','text/html');
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;
        System.debug(RestContext.response);
        List<String> items = new List<String>();
        for(String key : RestContext.request.headers.keySet()) {
            items.add(key + ' => ' + RestContext.request.headers.get(key));
        }
        
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('<html><body><span>Headers</span><div>' + String.join(items,'<br/>') + '</div><br/><br/><span>Request Body</span><div>' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(), 'utf-8') + '</div><br/><br/><span>Params</span><div>' + RestContext.request.params + '</div></body></html>');
    }

}
```

When I run this I am able to see the response but the body appears to be blank rather than populated with the value of the parameters. Is there another way that I should be attempting to access the payload parameter within my code?

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was bad testing on my part. I was sending an empty string from my VS Code manual REST Posts.

Here is how I was able to get the content of the Post that was in application/x-www-form-urlencoded

RestContext.request.params.get('payload');

That grabbed the body parameter named payload. Presuming I had a form with a bunch of different input boxes you could surmise what the other names would be or inspect RestContext.request.params

The following minimal code will echo back the urlencoded content I received that was in the payload parameter.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/slack/*')
global class REST_Slack  {

    @HttpPost global static void doPost() {
        RestContext.response.headers.put('Content-Type','text/html');
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;  
        RestContext.response.responseBody = 
        Blob.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('payload'));
}

}
```

My content happens to be in JSON format within the payload however this may not be true for everyone so I left the content generic or whatever Content-Type makes the most sense for how you want to process the response.